# Aspectj and initialization

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I would like to use initialization with aspectj.

```
@Aspect
public class TotoAspect
{
    @Before("initialization( *.new(..))")
    public void test(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint) throws AuditReactiveException
    {
        System.err.println("I AM HERE");
    }
}
```

But, the message was not print with

```
new ABC();
```

I use the java agent for aspectj.

Where is the mistake ?

Comment: This question is still listed as unanswered. Would you please accept and upvote my answer if it seems appropriate? Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Well, actually on your console you should see something like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.aspectj.lang.NoAspectBoundException: Exception while initializing de.scrum_master.aspect.TotoAspect: org.aspectj.lang.NoAspectBoundException: de.scrum_master.aspect.TotoAspect
    at de.scrum_master.aspect.TotoAspect.aspectOf(TotoAspect.java:1)
    at de.scrum_master.app.ABC.<init>(ABC.java:4)
    at de.scrum_master.app.ABC.main(ABC.java:10)
Caused by: org.aspectj.lang.NoAspectBoundException: de.scrum_master.aspect.TotoAspect
    at de.scrum_master.aspect.TotoAspect.aspectOf(TotoAspect.java:1)
    at de.scrum_master.aspect.TotoAspect.<init>(TotoAspect.java:10)
    at de.scrum_master.aspect.TotoAspect.ajc$postClinit(TotoAspect.java:1)
    at de.scrum_master.aspect.TotoAspect.<clinit>(TotoAspect.java:1)
    ... 2 more
```

This is because your advice is targetting all constructors, even its own aspect's one. You need to exclude it. Here is a compileable code sample:

**Exception class:**

This is to demonstrate that your pointcut also matches the exception's constructor.

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class AuditReactiveException extends Exception {
    public AuditReactiveException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

**Sample driver class with main method:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class ABC {
    public ABC() throws AuditReactiveException {
        System.err.println("Creating ABC object");
        throw new AuditReactiveException("Something went wrong");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws AuditReactiveException {
        new ABC();
    }
}
```

**Aspect with modified pointcut:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

import de.scrum_master.app.AuditReactiveException;

@Aspect
public class TotoAspect {
    @Before("initialization(*.new(..)) && !within(TotoAspect)")
    public void test(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint) throws AuditReactiveException {
        System.err.println(thisJoinPoint);
    }
}
```

**Sample output:**

```
initialization(de.scrum_master.app.ABC())
Creating ABC object
initialization(de.scrum_master.app.AuditReactiveException(String))
Exception in thread "main" de.scrum_master.app.AuditReactiveException: Something went wrong
    at de.scrum_master.app.ABC.<init>(ABC.java:6)
    at de.scrum_master.app.ABC.main(ABC.java:10)
```

You might also want to exclude the exception constructor, i.e. you should narrow down the pointcut's scope with package and/or class names. Check out the AspectJ documentation for pointcut syntax description, e.g. how to use jokers like `*` or `..`.